# Google appengine: module not starting with basic_scaling

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

Basically, I have a backend as a module that I only want one instance of at any given time. My requirement was that it doesn't scale past 1 instance, but it still shutsdown when there are no requests.

So I opted for `basic_scaling`.
It worked as expected on the development server. But as soon as I deployed it onto GAE, I noticed that the backend wasn't starting. I would get timeout messages when I visit a backend URL:

```
Error: Server Error

The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Here's the app.yaml file that goes with the backend module:

```
application: vim-colorsseum
module: backend
version: alpha
runtime: go
api_version: go1
basic_scaling:
    max_instances: 1

handlers:
    - url: /api.*
      script: _go_app
    - url: /reward.*
      script: _go_app
```

I redeployed the backend without the `basic_scaling` clause and everything worked.r

Out of curiosity, I also tried turning the `max_instances` knob up to 11. I thought that maybe 1 might have been too small for appengine.

Any idea how to get GAE to deploy my module?

Comment: what's the error on the logs?

Comment: Ah. I didn't know how to get to the logs before. But now that I've checked, it's flooded with requests to `/_ah/start` and complaints about not having a handler set up.

Should I set up a handler in the app itself, or is putting it into the yaml file enough? Weird that the development server doesn't match production for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the logs, which should've been the first thing I checked. If anyone didn't know, it's `monitoring > logs` in the developer console.

The problem was that I had no handler set up for the appengine request `/_ah/start` I put that into the yaml and put in an empty handler in my app. Now it starts up as expected